# How to run a script by shortkey in elementaryOS?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, elementary-os, macro

I want to be able to run certain scripts by shortcut the way I do in ubuntu - for example some similar to [this awesome script](https://askubuntu.com/a/222340/47206). (On that model I can search google the text selected in any text editor, or even translate it various languages, search it on different sites, etc).

How to use this type of script in elementaryOS?

Comment: I guess I'm not in this question's target audience, but I first interpreted the expression “this awesome script” as refering to [awesome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Awesome_(window_manager)).

Comment: @Gilles - I am not a native English speaker, but neither am I a computer 'connaisseur' (OR *connoisseur*, as they say in US), and maybe that is why I'm so impressed by such scripts, which seem mysterious, quite magic, *awesome* (in the -colloquial- sense of excellent, exciting, remarkable: "Awesome, dude!").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems elementary-tweaks has no longer key bindings in elementary Freya. But luckily there is mode to bind keys in Freya also. You can use program named xbindkeys. Details about how to configure and use it you can find [here](https://fravaccaro.wordpress.com/2015/04/14/keybindings-and-super-to-start-the-menu-in-elementary-os-0-3-freya/).

#### excerpt

> We only need xbindkeys, a simple yet powerful command line tool to
>   bind commands to a certain key or keys combinations. The program can
>   be installed via terminal typing:
>
> ```
>    $ sudo apt-get install xbindkeys
> ```
>
> After the installation, if you try to run the application, you will be
>   warmed to create a configuration file. As user, type:
>
> ```
>    $ touch ~/.xbindkeysrc
> ```
>
> or, alternatively:
>
> ```
>    $ xbindkeys --defaults > ~/.xbindkeysrc
> ```
>
> Then edit the file:
>
> ```
>    $ nano ~/.xbindkeysrc
> ```
>
> And type, before the end section:
>
> ```
>    "slingshot-launcher"
>    Super_L
> ```
>
> so it will look like this:
>
> ```
>    xbindkeys
> ```
>
> Then press CTRL+X to save and exit.
>
> Of course, xbindkeys can be used to bind also different commands to
>   different keys. The values are written as:
>
> ```
>    "command"
>    state (0x8) and keycode (32)
>    keysyms associated with the given keycodes
> ```
>
> To find the last two values (which, as we’ve seen, can be used
>   indifferently), type
>
> ```
>    $ xbindkeys -k
> ```
>
> then, in the blank window that’ll be open, type the key or the desired
>   keys combination. The result will appear in the terminal.

Comment: indeed. thanks for reviving this post. i was already using xbindkeys in Freya after [asking on eOS g+](https://plus.google.com/+CipricusCipriq/posts/KZYnySPibLV),  but had lost track of my question here :) -- only that you should edit the answer to add info on the very useful GUI xbindkeys-config, more [here](http://www.butlerpc.net/blog/2011/01/using-xbindkeys-on-ubuntu-linux-to-remap-key-commands/). or should i edit your answer?

Comment: xbindkeys is indeed the answer, but setting Super key for slingshot is not what I am asking, you have just pasted from that link. it also interferes with other shortkeys, not only those explicitly using Super key in some combination, but also on many laptops that have the Display key mapped like in windows (Super-p): clicking Display to switch between displays will show slingshot, clicking it again will type P in slingshot. So you should remove that, it is beyond the point of my question

Answer (score 1):

Worked in Luna, not available in Freya anymore!

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:versable/elementary-update
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install elementary-tweaks
```

In System settings -> Tweaks -> Shortcuts

'+' to add new shortkey

use a command like `sh /path/to/script`

[image]

---

In order to run the script, `xclip` is needed.

```
sudo apt-get install xclip
```